# Selenium find class with index

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord

Hey all trust that you're well, I'm trying to find **elements by class_name** and loop through them, however, they all have the same **class_name**.

I've discovered that **they contain different index numbers** and I'm trying to utilise that to loop through them

**Example of the element and the index:**

```
<div class="member-2gU6Ar container-1oeRFJ clickable-28SzVr" aria-controls="popout_4188" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" colorroleid="987314373729067059" index="0" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="members-987320208253394947___0">
```

```
<div class="member-2gU6Ar container-1oeRFJ clickable-28SzVr" aria-controls="popout_4184" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" colorroleid="987324577870929940" index="1" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="members-987320208253394947___1">
```

**My code:**

```
    users = bot.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'member-2gU6Ar')
        
    time.sleep(5)

    try:
        for user in users:
            user.click()
            message = bot.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/input[1]')
            time.sleep(5)
            message.send_keys('Automated' + Keys.ENTER)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        skip
```

[image: first user in the list to the left of the inspect page]

[image: second user in the list to the left of the inspect page]

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Hey @ArundeepChohan I did not receive any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that you see over here `member-2gU6Ar container-1oeRFJ clickable-28SzVr` is not a single class, it is a combination of multiple classes separated with space.

So using `member-2gU6Ar` would not work as expected.

You can remove the spaces and put a `.` to make a `CSS selector` though.

```
div.member-2gU6Ar.container-1oeRFJ.clickable-28SzVr
```

I would not really suggest that since I see it contains alpha numeric string, that may get change with the time.

Here I have written an xpath:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'member') and contains(@class, 'container') and @index]
```

this should match all the divs with the specified attribute.

You can use it probably like this:

```
users = bot.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class,'member') and contains(@class, 'container') and @index]")
i = 1
time.sleep(5)
try:
    for user in users:
        ele = bot.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[starts-with(@class,'member') and contains(@class, 'container') and @index= '{i}']")
        ele.click()
        message = bot.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/input[1]')
        time.sleep(5)
        message.send_keys('Automated' + Keys.ENTER)
        i = i + 1
except NoSuchElementException:
    skip
```

However I would recommend you to use a relative xpath and not absolute xpath `//body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/input[1]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @cruisepandey trust that you're well, truly appreciated would the xpath not be offset by the position of the item?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9gBa2yPG @cruisepandey on line 12 the page refreshes, is there a method I could create that stores the value and moves to the next index even if the page refreshes?

Comment: Could not understand you. `users` is a list of web element and you can print the size of it and iterate over the list to perform some operation one by one? On line 12 `bot.get('https://discord.com/channels/982777146256818207/986367081496862760')` you've got this, Now I don't know what is those ids? Are we getting the ids from the list ?

Comment: what I'm doing is sending a message to individual users, upon sending the message it redirects me to the users dm.

 I use:
```bot.get('https://discord.com/channels/982777146256818207/986367081496862760')```

to redirect me back to the page where I proceed to get the next user.

Each user has the same class, however the index progresses by one for each user, could I manipulate and store that value to get the next user in the list and not start from the top once I refresh the page?

Comment: I've added support images above for more insight.

Comment: You can parameterized the index like above (Please see updated code above), I hope that will solve the issue.

Comment: Truly appreciated champ!, it worked.